# bash extract first number from filename

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, rename, mv

I'm trying to move files like this:

```
...
DLG023-00-01-sprite.TextGrid.json
DLG023-00-01.prosody.json
DLG023-01-01-sprite.ogg
DLG023-00-02-sprite.TextGrid.json
DLG023-00-02.prosody.json
DLG023-01-02-sprite.ogg
...
DLG028-00-01-sprite.TextGrid.json
DLG028-00-01.prosody.json
DLG028-01-01-sprite.ogg
...
```

into their respective folders, e.g.: move the file to `dialogue023/` when it starts with `DLG023`; to `dialogue024/` when it starts with `DLG024`; and so on.

All of the files and directories are at the same level.

In other words, I'm trying to produce commands like this one:

```
mv DLG023-00-01-sprite.ogg dialogue023/
```

**How can I extract the first number from the filename?**

So far I've got this:

```
for i in DLG*-*-*-sprite.ogg; do echo "${i//[^0-9]}";done
```

But this outputs all of the digits (e.g.: 230001) when I only want the first one (e.g.: 23).

Comment: It doesn't actually *extract* the numbers, so it's not an answer to the question, but in principle you can also do something like `for num in $(seq -f '%03g' 1 999); do test -d dialogue${num}||mkdir dialogue${num}; mv -t  dialogue${num} DLG${num}-*; done` followed by `rmdir dialogue*` -- the `-f '%03g'` means all numbers are zero-padded to at least three digits, and since 999 fits into three digits all numbers will become three digits long in the directory names. Plain `rmdir` fails if the directory is not empty, so is safe. Brace for unimportant error output from `mv` about nonexistent files.

Comment: Is it always chars 4-6?

Comment: Thank you Michael, that's the clever way to go about it.

Comment: It's always chars 3-6 (or 4-6 for now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using OS X, which doesn't have the `-t` option in `mv`. This will be painfully slow if the script is processing thousands of files.

```
    for file in DLG*; do
    # Extract the three digits after DLG
    getnum=${file%%-*}
    getnum=${getnum#???}

    # make the directory dialogue### or exit if there is an error
    echo mkdir -p "dialogue${getnum}" || exit

    echo mv "$file" "dialogue${getnum}"
    done
```

Remove the `echo` before `mkdir` and `mv` if the output is satifactory.

Comment: Works like a charm. It does not happen in the blink of an eye but does happen in seconds for 19 folders. Out of sheer curiosity: is there a way to extract the three digits in just one step?

Comment: @Fabien Snauwaert- You could use substring expansion in one step instead of substring removal but substring expansion is not available in every shell.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

```
for i in DLG*-\*-\*-sprite.ogg; do echo "${i//[^0-9]}" | head -c 2; echo ;done
```

If you are sure they are all same length:

```
for i in DLG*-\*-\*-sprite.ogg; do echo "${i:3:3}" ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the mv command using this:

```
for f in DLG*; do echo "$f" | sed 's/DLG\([0-9]\+\).*/mv "\0" "dialogue\1\/"/g'; done
```

Now, the command are printed like this:

```
mv "DLG023-00-01.prosody.json" "dialogue023/"
[...]
mv "DLG028-00-01.prosody.json" "dialogue028/"
[...]
```

If it is what you want, just pipe that output to `bash` and it will be executed:

```
for f in DLG*; do echo "$f" | sed 's/DLG\([0-9]\+\).*/mv "\0" "dialogue\1\/"/g'; done | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution using `find`:

```
find . -name DLG* -exec bash -c 'DEST=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/DLG([0-9]+)-.*/dialogue\1/"); mkdir "$DEST"; mv "$0" "$DEST"' {} \;
```

- `find` command look for `DLG*` files from this directory.
- For every result execute the `bash -c` sentence.

In the `bash` sentence:

- `DEST=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/DLG([0-9]+)-.*/dialogue\1/");` picks every result from find (`$0`) and using `sed` replace the all numbers before the first `-` (DLG([0-9]+)-.*) with `dialogue` following with those numbers (`dialogue\1`) and put in on a variable called `DEST`.
- `mkdir "$DEST"` creates the required folder.
- `mv "$0" "$DEST"'` moves the file to that directory.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.